# How to filter datagridview when rows are added manually in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i filter the rows using `textBox` when rows are added manually

Here is my code:

```
int n = XML_Grid.Rows.Add();
XML_Grid.ClearSelection();
XML_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = FileName;
XML_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = Name;
XML_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = ID;
XML_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = Date;
```

If not possible to filter how can i add the rows using `datatable` like i did for the `DataGridView` in the same way?

**Note: This question could be duplicate but i didn't find any solution to my problem**

Comment: what did u code so far to get filtered data from textbox? so we can provide u exact solution

Comment: `XML_Grid.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FileName LIKE '{0}%'", txt_FileName.Text);` I tried this but the `datagridview` doesn't contain the definition of `DefaultView` this code could work if i use `dataTable`

Comment: did u used `Windows Form Application` or `WPF`?

Comment: Already mention `winforms` in `Tags`

Comment: try this `(XML_Grid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FileName LIKE '{0}%'", txt_FileName.Text);` and let me know

Comment: Getting error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: try to add breakpoint on same line and watch `XML_Grid.DataSource` is getting null or or any other value is null?

Comment: `XML_Grid.DataSource` is null.

Comment: If you can convert my manually code using `Datatable` then i can filter it by my self.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180569/discussion-between-ershoaib-and-usama).

Comment: Yes, it is clearly recommended to a) put the data into a DataTable. and b) to filter inset a BindingSource between DGV.DataSource and the DataTable. The you can use RowFilter. Many examples for both around..

Comment: @Usama, view messages in chat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your Xml data to `DataTable` and then set this `DataTable` to `XML_Grid.DataSource`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("FileName");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Date");

XML_Grid.Rows.Clear();
lbl_Path.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.xml");

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Emisor");
XmlNodeList nodes1 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Comprobante");

foreach (string tot_file in files)
{
    doc.Load(tot_file);
    string FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tot_file);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        string Name = nodes[i].Attributes["Nombre"].Value;
        string ID = nodes[i].Attributes["Rfc"].Value;
        string Date = nodes1[i].Attributes["Fecha"].Value;

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["FileName"] = FileName;
        row["Name"] = Name;
        row["ID"] = ID;
        row["Date"] = Date;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

XML_Grid.DataSource = dt;
```

And in your textbox textchanged event add below like to filter data.

```
(XML_Grid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FileName LIKE '{0}%'", txt_FileName.Text)
```

**Edit:**

If you want to add the rows to your existing columns that you added through add column from datagridview then just set `DataPropertyName` for each of column of `XML_Grid` to column name of `DataTable` like

```
XML_Grid.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "FileName";
XML_Grid.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Name";
XML_Grid.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "ID";
XML_Grid.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Date";
```

Where 0,1,2,3 are the index of your column. Verify your column index respective to you existing columns in `XML_Grid`.

Add above line of code just above to `XML_Grid.Rows.Clear();`

Alternative to above code is you can set `DataPropertyName` for each of column from Property Window of datagridview.

Select `XML_Grid`  ==> Open Property Window ==> Select `Columns` Property ==> Choose your column ==> And set its `DataPropertyName` from (none) to "FileName".

And same for all of your remaining columns.

Comment: @Usama, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: +1 answer is useful but I already tried this code and it's working fine i don't want to add columns by code i already added Columns in datagridiew how can i add the rows to my existing columns that i added through add column from datagridview?

Comment: @Usama, view the **Edit** section in answer might be it help you :) and let me know.

Comment: `Column` FileName doesn't belong to table. Not working

Comment: did u remove these codes `dt.Columns.Add("FileName");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Date");`?

Comment: try to keep datatable and all of its code similar to my answer then after you may edit by your choice

Comment: Yes i remove these codes and replace with your Edited code.

Comment: ok  keep all code in answer as it is and add my edit section code to just above `DataTable dt = new DataTable();`   do not remove or replace any code

Comment: i m live here and waiting to hear from you :)

Comment: Finally everythings work but date filter didn't `string result = "Date >= "+ Date_From + " AND Date <= " + Date_To + " ";
            dt.Select(result);`

Comment: you have to convert date in datagridview and in xml to `DateTime` and then compare both...

Comment: Everything works fine another error comes when selecting the folder again  Column `FileName` already belongs to Datatable.

Comment: try to add `DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("FileName");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Date");
` these line globally. then error not comes

Comment: Solved it by myself, Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)